# add li & also clear a input field once a submit button is clicked jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Once the submit button is pressed I want to add the li which works with this code but I also want to clear the input filed as well. Where do I add a .reset? or other method, I did a .reset() after the input and does not work. Maybe the positioning is off?

```js
$('.sub').click(function(e){
    var userInput = $('#input').val();
    $('#ul').append('<li>'+userInput+'</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Enter food here</h2>
    <input id = 'input'></input>
    <button class ='sub'>Submit</button>
</div>
    <div class = 'para'>
        <h2>Shopping List</h2>
        <ul id = 'ul'>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This `<input id = 'input'></input>` should be `<input type="text" id="input" />`...and in your javascript code just add this line `$('#input').val('');` after the `append` line.

Comment: Also cache the input lookup in a variable so you don't have to do it twice.

Answer (score 1):

`.reset()` function works on form. You might need to wrap your HTML in the form and then do as follows -

```js
$('.sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var userInput = $('#input').val();
    $('#ul').append('<li>'+userInput+'</li>');
    $('form')[0].reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h2>Enter food here</h2>
  <div>
    <input id = 'input'></input>
    <button class ='sub' type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
    <div class = 'para'>
       <h2>Shopping List</h2>
   <ul id = 'ul'>
    </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear a input field just set it's value to an empty string like so:

```
$('#input').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify `input` and add one line `JS` to make input empty

```js
$('.sub').click(function(e){
     var userInput = $('#input').val();
     $('#ul').append('<li>'+userInput+'</li>');
      $('#input').val('');
      
    
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Enter food here</h2>
    
 
    <input id= "input" type="text" />


   <button class ='sub'>Submit</button>
</div>
   <div class = 'para'>
    <h2>Shopping List</h2>
   <ul id = 'ul'>
    </ul>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the val to empty string ("")

```js
$('.sub').click(function(e){
    var userInput = $('#input').val();
    $('#ul').append('<li>'+userInput+'</li>');
    $('#input').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Enter food here</h2>
    <input id = 'input'></input>
    <button class ='sub'>Submit</button>
</div>
    <div class = 'para'>
        <h2>Shopping List</h2>
        <ul id = 'ul'>
        </ul>
    </div>
```